# Spacing between two strings in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm taking this course online, and I can't really go back cause there are 23 lessons I've already finished and I don't remember which one of them told me about spacing something inside of a string

So basically it is printing out

```
Joe Bloggs   37
Sarah Smith   20
```

I want there to be a space between the name and the age of `person1` and `person2`.

How would I go about doing that?

I tried `\n` and `\t` but my compiler yells at me.
And I'm still a beginner so I don't understand what the error message means.

here's the code:

```
class Person {

    String name;
    int age;

}


public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.name = "Joe Bloggs";
        person1.age = 37;

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.name = "Sarah Smith";
        person2.age = 20;

        System.out.println(person1.name + person1.age);
        System.out.println(person2.name + person2.age);

    }

}
```

Comment: System.out.println(person1.name+" "+person1.age);

Comment: Duhhh, that slipped my mind

Haha thanks for helping me out

Comment: LostMind, it just slipped my mind momentarily. And I'm not finished. If you would of read, you would of seen that I said I'm still a beginner and still in the class.

Comment: And BTW thanks for purposely not answering my question and posting a useless response

Comment: You can override toString() method of Person class as below,
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " +age;
    }
So when you print any Person object in System.out.println(anyPersonObject);
It prints toString() method return value.

Comment: @ManjunathDR _Why don't you submit this as an answer?_

Comment: use string.format() follow this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the `String.format` method as in

```
Sytem.out.println (String.format("%s %d", person1.name, person1.age));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override toString() method of Person class as below,

```
@Override 
public String toString() { 
return name + " " +age; 
}
```

So when you print any Person object in

```
System.out.println(anyPersonObject);
```

It prints toString() method return value.

Comment: IMHO overriding `toString` is a bad idea as it fixes you into a single usage for the method, where it is better used to display debug/diagnostic information. A better idea would be to provide a formatter of some kind. Just saying

Comment: @MadProgrammer Agreed.But why not this could be the proper way of guiding the OP for printing the objects and not suggesting just space in between attributes every time,what if there are _many attributes_.

Comment: @TAsk Then provide a formatter.  What if you only want to show "some" of the attributes some of the time. Best practices make perfect ;) - This is just my opinion, but I have a massive dislike for overriding `toString` for this use case, that's just me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer If there are many attributes then I will go for formatter defeineitly!!! :) :) but still `toString` is one of the `good-(some side effect)` option.

Answer (score 1):

Because person1.name is a string, and person1.age is an int (i assume), when you call:

```
System.out.println(person1.name + person2.age);
```

.. you are actually concatenating the 2 attributes into one string.

If the two fields were both ints, then the same operation would result in the 2 numbers being added, but adding an int to a string will result in string concatenation.

To add the two together with spacing, you can call:

```
System.out.println(person1.name + " " + person2.age);
```

This will print person1.name, followed by a space (" "), followed by person2.age.
Whatever is inside your " " will be printed, so you could print a : or a ; for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is way to format the String.

```
    String result1 = String.format("%s %d", person1.name, person1.age);
    System.out.println(result1);//Result - Bloggs 37

    String result2 = String.format("%s is %d old", person1.name, person1.age);
    System.out.println(result2);//Result - Joe Bloggs is 37 old

    String result3 = String.format("%s\t%d", person1.name, person1.age);
    System.out.println(result3);//Result - Joe Bloggs   37
```

I hope it helps you.